# Consulta retornar em qual campo está o valor

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma consulta em PHP + MySQL:

```
SELECT * From tb WHERE campo1='valor' or campo2='valor' or campo3='valor'
```

Gostaria que a consulta me retornasse em qual dos campos foi achado o valor.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-pt, por favor leia o [manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/13561), principalmente a seção [Não fornecer um código Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6252/13561)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize CASE / WHEN:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN campo1='valor' THEN 'campo1' WHEN campo2='valor' THEN 'campo2' ELSE 'campo3' END AS campo
FROM tb 
WHERE campo1='valor' or campo2='valor' or campo3='valor'
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado